# Hangfire Recurring job runs every 30 minutes while it's still unfinished

Tags: asp.net-core, hangfire

I'm using Hangfire to run jobs that take roughly 2 hours. I have noticed that every 30 minutes the job re occurs while the previous one is still working. So If I have Job A which starts at a specific time, after 30 minutes another job A will start running while previous one is still in processing state.

ConfigureServices():

```
services.AddHangfire(config => config
        .UseSimpleAssemblyNameTypeSerializer()
        .UseDefaultTypeSerializer()
        .UseMemoryStorage());



        services.AddHangfireServer();
```

Configure():

```
app.UseHangfireDashboard();

RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<ISender>(i => i.A(), Cron.Daily(8, 0), timeZone: TimeZoneInfo.Local);
```

I have checked the Method which is run for errors, exceptions and etc, just to make sure job is not retried because of that. I think that's not a case after a lot of testing.

any kind of help would be appreciated

Comment: how many workers you have defined?

Comment: Have you looked into using `DisableConcurrentExecution` to prevent multiple instances of the same job from executing?

Comment: I will try DisablingConcurrentExecution and about workers - I have not changed it, I think it's 20

Comment: DisableConcurrentExecution did not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is right way, but it solved the problem for me.

It was caused by **UseMemoryStorage()** in **ConfigureServices()**.

Passing options like the example below will restrict a job to reoccur after 30 minutes by default or whatever will be indicated in options.

```
var options = new MemoryStorageOptions
{
    FetchNextJobTimeout = TimeSpan.FromHours(10)
};

services.AddHangfire(config => config.SetDataCompatibilityLevel(CompatibilityLevel.Version_170)
  .UseSimpleAssemblyNameTypeSerializer()
  .UseDefaultTypeSerializer()
  .UseMemoryStorage(options));
```